# How do I print a specific value from API output?

Tags: python, api

I want to print the price from this API. How do I print the specific value of 'price' from the json output?

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://api.oilpriceapi.com/v1/prices/latest'
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Token XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.get(url = url, headers = headers)
data = response.json()
print(data)
{'status': 'success', 'data': {'price': 36.19, 'formatted': '$36.19', 'currency': 'USD', 'code': 'BRENT_CRUDE_USD', 'created_at': '2020-06-02T22:11:30.159Z', 'type': 'spot_price'}}
```

Comment: `print(data['data']['price'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so:

```
print(data['status']) // success
print(data['data']['price']) // 36.19
```